# Git push old version of a "--skip-worktree" file

Tags: git, github

I'm using Git to transfer code from a DEV machine to a PROD machine.
Most of the code is common, but I have specific configuration files that need to be different between the two.

I want my git to represent the current state of the PROD machine. The idea is to push most files from DEV, and only specific local_config_file from PROD. Therefore I executed the following command on DEV so that the DEV local_config_file would not impact, or be impacted by GIT:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree local_config_file
```

However, when I try to push code from DEV to git I get this error :

```
error: failed to push some refs to [my_git]
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
```

And when I run `git diff origin/branchName branchName`  (still on DEV), it only shows me differences from files I want to push (that's ok ...) and differences from an old version of the local_config_file, despite being set as skip-worktree.

For experimental purpose, I tried to push force into git and end up with the old version of my local_config_file in git ...

Anyone knows how to solve this ? Thanks for your help

Comment: The message you've shown is about the state of the _branch history_, not any particular files. You have branches on the two machines with the same name but different histories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want my git to represent the current state of the PROD machine.

OK.

Remember that Git stores *commits*, not files.  Commits store files—in fact, each commit contains a full snapshot of *every* file—but Git works one *commit* at a time.  Each Git repository is, at its heart, a collection of commits, and each repository either has some commit, or lacks it.  The commit is thus all-or-nothing: *all* of the files, or else you don't have the commit at all.

> The idea is to push most files from DEV ...

You cannot do this in Git.  You must push *commits*.

> ... and only specific local_config_file from PROD. Therefore I executed the following command on DEV so that the DEV local_config_file would not impact, or be impacted by GIT:
>
> ```
> git update-index --skip-worktree local_config_file
> ```

This does not do what I think you think it does.  That's not the immediate source of the next problem, but it is something you will need to clear up before you can get what you want.

> ```
> error: failed to push some refs to [my_git]
> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
> hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
> hint: before pushing again.
> ```

This, on the other hand, means more or less what it says.  Its advice may be slightly wrong for your particular situation, though.

#### What to know about commits and Git's index

When using Git, remember these things:

- Git is all about the commits.  Branches—more specifically branch *names*—are useful to you (and to Git to get it to help you) but Git is really about the *commits*.
- Every commit has a unique number.  This number is a random-looking (but not at all random) *hash ID*, rather than a nice simple counting number, but they are still numbered.  This lets any two Gits talk to each other and agree as to whether they have, or lack, some particular commit, just by comparing the commit numbers.
- Each commit has two parts: a snapshot (of all files) stored in a read-only, Git-only, frozen-for-all-time but de-duplicated format—this saves lots of space since most files mostly just get re-used in the next commit—plus some *metadata*, i.e., information about the commit itself.  The metadata include things like who made the commit, when, and why (log message).  This also includes, though, the commit number of the *previous* commit.

Because the files inside a commit are frozen, de-duplicated, and Git-only, they have to be extracted *out* of a commit for you to use them.  The place where these files are defrosted and decompressed—reconstituted or rehydrated for your use—is called your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  You pick some commit—ultimately, by its internal commit number—and ask Git to extract that commit.  Git does so, and now you have all the files *from* that commit.

In this sense, you have two copies of every file: the current commit has the frozen and de-duplicated Git-only copy, and your work-tree has the ordinary format copy that you can work with.

Here's where Git gets a bit tricky, though: to make a *new* commit, Git doesn't use your work-tree copy!  That copy is *yours*, not Git's.  Instead, Git sneakily keeps a *third* copy.  It's not exactly a copy, because it's pre-de-duplicated, but it acts like one.  This third copy is in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*.

When you first check out a commit, Git fills in its index from that commit, and then fills your work-tree from the files from that commit too.  If you change your work-tree copy of some file, you generally want to use `git add`, which tells Git: *Copy the work-tree copy back into the index, replacing the copy that was there before.*  That way, the index always holds your *proposed next commit*.  (The files in the index are kept in the frozen and de-duplicated format, ready to go, making the next commit go fast, too.  The `git add` step does the compressing  and de-duplicating.)

#### What skip-worktree does

What the `--skip-worktree` bit does is tell Git: *If my work-tree copy doesn't match your index copy, that's OK.  Don't say anything about it.  Don't use the work-tree copy to update the index copy either.  Just skip right over the work-tree copy.*  That way, your proposed *next* commit keeps the index copy that you extracted from some existing commit.

When you use `git checkout` to switch to some other existing commit, though, Git will still copy the frozen-format file into the index (and sometimes into your work-tree too: these details vary with the use of Git's *sparse checkout* mode).  The `--skip-worktree` bit just means it won't complain when *you* change the work-tree copy, and `git add` *won't* update the index copy.

It's time to bring this part back to your particular issue:

> I want [to make a new commit] to represent the current state of the PROD machine.

Git will make a new commit from the files that are in Git's index, not from the files in your work-tree.  So, to do this, you must load your own Git's index with the correct files.

> The idea is to [use] most[ly] files from DEV and only specific local_config_file from PROD ...

So, to do *this*, you should make sure that Git's index copy of this local config file matches the one on PROD.  If it doesn't:

1. move the local config file out of the way;
2. clear the `--skip-worktree` flag (`git update-index --no-skip-worktree local_config_file`);
3. install the PROD config file as the local config file;
4. use `git add` to copy the correct file into Git's index;
5. feel free to switch the config back and/or set flags again, now that the index copy matches the file you'd like to have in the *next* commit.

There are several alternatives to this process.  For instance, a pretty standard way to deal with this is to be sure *never to store any actual configuration file in Git at all*.  Store only *sample* or *default* configurations; for a real, live configuration, use the sample or default to whatever extent it's useful, but add whatever customization is required, then *don't* have Git manage that file at all.  (Unfortunately, having put the configuration into Git, any update that *removes* the file from Git will cause a Git update step to remove the file from the work-tree.  So at this point, unless you're willing to go through a painful switchover, you're a bit stuck here.)

#### How to see what's actually in an index file

When you have set the `--skip-worktree` flag set on the index copy of a file, it's hard to know what's actually *in* the index copy, because Git doesn't show you the file directly.  Git normally just shows you *whether the index copy matches the work-tree copy*.  Setting `--skip-worktree` tells Git: *don't bother comparing* (index and work-tree copies) as well as suppressing updates.

You can, however, view the index contents directly:

```
$ echo 'skip this in worktree' > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m 'add file to skip'
[master 7cee93e] add file to skip
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
$ git update-index --skip-worktree file
$ ls
file    README
$ git cat-file -p :file
skip this in worktree
$ echo more >> file
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ cat file
skip this in worktree
more
$ git add -f file
$ git cat-file -p :file
skip this in worktree
$
```

The above shows how, despite my changes to file `file`, `git status` and `git add` leave the *index* copy alone.  But I can *view* the index copy with `git cat-file -p :file`.  The leading colon `:` here means *let me see the copy that is in the index*.

If I unset the `--skip-worktree` flag, `git status` starts saying more:

```
$ git update-index --no-skip-worktree file
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Again, all that `--skip-worktree` does is make sure that `git status` doesn't *complain* and `git add` doesn't actually *add*.  The index copy of file `file` is still there, and still goes into new commits I make.

#### `the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart`

Your last problem is here.  Remember how, as mentioned above, each commit has two parts:

- The *data* in a commit is a snapshot of all files.
- The *metadata* in a commit is information about the commit, including author and committer (name and email addresses), date-and-time-stamps, and so on.

In the metadata, each commit stores the unique number of its immediate predecessor commit (or for a merge commit, predecessor commits, plural).  That is, given some commit, Git can find the commit that comes *before* that commit.  Git calls this stored hash ID the *parent* of the commit.

Git cannot go forward in time with this information.  Git can only go *backwards*.  But that is sufficient: given the commit number—the hash ID—of the *latest* commit, Git can work *backwards* from there, to earlier commits.

These are the actual branches in Git.  The *names*—the branch names like `master` and `develop`—are just a trick: each name stores the random-looking hash ID of the *last* commit that is to be considered part of that branch.  This means that it's the commits themselves that matter.  The *names* just let you, or Git, get started.

We can draw this situation like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain of commits.  To find `H`'s hash ID quickly, Git has a name, like `master`, store that hash ID:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Using that hash ID, Git can extract commit `H`, or, if you ask it to, use `H`'s stored parent hash ID—the one for `G`—go back in time one commit to commit `G` and extract that commit.  Having found commit `G`, Git can use its stored parent hash ID, which locates `F`, to extract commit `F`.  Having found that commit, Git can go back even further, if and when necessary.

To make a *new* commit that comes after commit `H`, Git:

1. gathers any necessary metadata: your name, your email address, and so on;
2. gets `H`'s hash ID (it's right there handy in the name `master`);
3. freezes this, plus all of the index copies of all files, into a new commit, which we'll call `I`; and last, in a sneaky but clever move
4. writes `I`'s new hash ID into the *name* master.

This means we go from:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

to:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

to:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

and now we have a new commit on `master`, that simply adds on to the chain.

To *send* this new commit to *some other* Git, we have our Git call up their Git, believing that *their* Git also has:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

in *its* set of commits and *its* branch names.  We have our Git send them our new commit `I`, so that they now have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

in *their* repository.  Then we have our Git ask them: *If it's OK, please set your `master` so that it refers to commit `I` now.*

When *they* say *no*, and add:

```
  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

what this means is that when we *assumed* they had:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

we were just plain *wrong*.  They had something like this instead:

```
             J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
```

in their repository.  We sent them our commit `I`, which says that commit `H` is its parent.  They said OK—that's fine—and they now have:

```
             J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I
```

But then we asked them to please, if it was OK, move *their* `master` to identify commit `I`.  If they were to do that, they would *lose* their commit `J`!

Remember, Git—*any* Git—works by starting with the branch name to find the *last* commit, then working *backwards*.  If we have them set their `master` to remember commit `I`, and they work backwards from there, they will have commit `I` preceded by commit `H`, and then from there backwards as before.  But commit `J` isn't *backwards* from `H`.  It's *forwards*.

#### How to proceed from here

What we need to do, then, if we don't want to have them throw away commit `J` after all, is *get their commit from them*.  We can have our Git call up their Git and *get* commit `J`, and put it into *our* Git.  This gives us:

```
             J   <-- origin/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

in *our* repository.  Our commit `I` still exists, and our `master` still *remembers* our commit `I`.

What we need now is to build some new commit—let's call it commit `K`, though in reality it will have some big ugly random-looking hash ID—that builds on their commit `J`.  We'll take our snapshot, in our commit `I`, and modify it into a snapshot that starts with their snapshot in `J` but takes whatever we *changed* when we went from `H` to `I`.

You have one extra complication, of course.  You have a configuration file in the way, that you decided should be stored in Git (a mistake, but one you are stuck with).  You may need to move *yours* out of the way—perhaps out of your own Git repository entirely—and put the production version in place, and clear the skip-worktree bit.

Once you have done all of that, you can have any commit—including `H`, `I`, and/or `J`—come out of your Git repository into your work-tree and into Git's index.  *Your* configuration is safely out of your work-tree entirely; you're working with the production version.  You can now copy commit `I` to a new commit `K` that follows `J`.  There are multiple ways to do that but perhaps the easiest is:

```
git checkout -b update-prod origin/master    # make a branch to use commit `J`
```

which gives you something that we can draw like this:

```
             J   <-- update-prod (HEAD), origin/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

It's now easy to use `git cherry-pick` to copy commit `I`.  Normally I would call the copy `I'`, but I've been using the name `K`, so let's write the command and draw the result:

```
git cherry-pick master

             J   <-- origin/master
            / \
...--F--G--H   K   <-- update-prod (HEAD)
            \
             I   <-- master
```

You can now rename your old `master` to `old-master` and your current `update-prod` to `master`:

```
git branch -m master old-master
git branch -m update-prod master
```

which gives you:

```
             J   <-- origin/master
            / \
...--F--G--H   K   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I   <-- old-master
```

(You probably don't even need the *name* `old-master` any more, but it does not hurt to leave it around for a while.)  Now you can set the skip-worktree bit on the configuration file again, copy the development configuration back into place, and test it as much as necessary.

When your testing is good, you can run:

```
git push origin master
```

This time, your Git calls up their Git, offers your new commit `K`, and then asks them to set their `master` to point to the now-shared commit `K`.  Their Git no longer has a reason to reject the request.  On their Git, then, this will produce:

```
...--F--G--H--J--K   <-- master
```

Commit `I` is not visible in their Git.  It may be in there, because you sent it earlier, but nobody can *find* it because the way we—including Git—*find* commits is to start with the branch names and use those to find the *last* commits, and then work backwards, and there is no *name* in *their* Git by which to find commit `I`.

Once you delete your own name `old-master`, you no longer have a convenient way to find commit `I` either, and it will be as though it never existed.  We'll have no reason to draw the commits with a kink in them, as your own Git will now have:

```
...--F--G--H--J--K   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

Your Git will update your own `origin/master`—your Git's memory of their Git's `master`—as soon as they accept your `git push` request.

Comment: This is what I call a detailed answer ! Many thanks, it solved everything